# How to center on a map by zip code for a specific country?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API v3 to handle a map. In addition I took an input/text and an input/button to let the user look for a zip code.

The map then should center on that zipcode. And it does! But on some zip codes I come to very exotic places.

The server, client and anything else is in Germany, so I would like to lock all queries to Germany. For example if I want to center on "92224" I don't see Bavaria, I get lost in Lithuania.

I'm using the following code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11147863/1565582) to center by command:

```
function codeAddress(zipCode) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipCode}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //Got result, center the map and put it out there
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

**Now how can I achieve that this query only will center on German zip codes?** (If it helps, German zip codes are always 5 numbers long.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to setup `componentRestrictions` and filter by country.

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderComponentRestrictions).

**Example**:

```
function codeAddress(zipCode) {

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address, "componentRestrictions":{"country":"DE"}
    }, function (results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

**Demo:**

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/8e6xh7sc/)</kbd>

**Note:**

As a side note, you cannot filter by multiple countries. This is a [long awaited feature](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4233) that Google still didn't implement until now.

**Edit:** 2017-04-19

Google has now implemented a way to filter by up to 5 countries: see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821685 I will not make any comment about how much useful this is...

Comment: Aaaaand it works! Perfect, thanks! :) Is there a way to tell Google Maps to center it with a disctance of ~100 km? Because on Lithuania it did, now it just centers.

Comment: I didn't get your question. What do you mean by *center with a distance*?

Comment: Sry. Your function centers well to the zip code I enter. But I then see the centered point in a distance what I had before. I would like to also set the distance of view to about 100 km. So that when you search for a zip code, you also see the surrounding scenery and not the whole country. :)

Comment: Well just set the zoom level to what you want. `map.setZoom(10)` for example. http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/8e6xh7sc/2/

Comment: Lucky easteregg, I guess: If you enter a zip code which may be valid but is not used in Germany, you're transfered to Mühlhausen. The Duke of Münchhausen is known to be a folklore about lying. (Don't know if Google intended this or if this is serendipity.)

Comment: Well... Nice story, but I don't think Mühlhausen/Münchhausen are related ;). If you check the results, it returns *Germany*. And that point is right in the middle of Germany. Why doesn't it return *ZERO_RESULTS* I can't tell though.

Comment: So Mühlhausen isnt even lying when they say theyre taking center... But thanks for that ticking off. :D

Comment: Maybe it doesnt get `ZERO_RESULTS` because of the language filter. So the code knows that it has to look in `Germany` but cant find any further. So it maybe returns the last known superior data.

Comment: You mean the country filter, right? The same *inexistent* zip code returns `ZERO_RESULTS` if no `componentRestrictions` is set on the country. So that sounds like it changes the behavior.

Comment: This is not working for me. Even in the fiddle. When i enter a nonexisting (in Germany) ZipCode (e.g 20030) i get centered on USA. Even though the componentRestrictions say country:DE