# angular js directive to plot marker on google map based on zipcode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to plot zip codes markers instead of lat and logs on google maps.
Is there any documentation available for this.
I am using angular js for my work.

the data is as follows.

```
}
"pageType": "ZIP",
"ZIP": {
    "90638": {
        "OVERALL": "320.00"
    },
    "75594": {
        "OVERALL": "2985.0"
    },
    "10997": {
        "OVERALL": "444"
    },
    "90639": {
        "OVERALL": "64.35"
    },
    "75595": {
        "OVERALL": "2562"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you using https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/? Or some other google maps Library?

Comment: Duplicate. This has been answered in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147803/how-to-use-zip-code-instead-lat-and-lng-in-google-maps-api).

Comment: will this solve your problem or do you still need help with the directive?

Comment: this is not the solution of my problem.I have a list of 20000 such zip to plot at one time.. google has limits for 5000 per hr.